# QtCreator fails to parse msbuild compile errors/warnings

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, ide, qt-creator

When I try to use QtCreator 3.3.2 to build a Visual Studio 2013 project, it does not put the errors and warnings in to the 'Issues' panel. They are visible in the compile output but unclickable. Here are the steps I have taken to reproduce this issue with a trivial example.

First I made a basic Win32 console application in Visual Studio and added a line to the `_tmain` function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   deliberately_missing_function(5);
   std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio reports a compilation error with `deliberately_missing_function`, as expected.

I create a new QtCreator project using the "Import Existing Project" template and save it in the same directory as the Visual Studio solution file. In the project settings, I make a custom process step in the build, and fill the command as `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` and arguments as `/p:Platform=Win32`

When building, the compile output shows:

```
(snip)
Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Portponky\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Portponky\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test\Test.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
(ClCompile target) -> 
  c:\users\Portponky\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\test\test\test.cpp(9): error C3861: 'deliberately_missing_function': identifier not found [C:\Users\Portponky\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test\Test.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

This is not picked up and shown in the Issues panel. My QtCreator is configured with the right compiler set up in the 'kits' section of options. I know that QtCreator is supposed to support reading msbuild errors, but I am confused as it doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is caused because the default error/warning parser for QtCreator as of 3.3.2 does not accept errors of the form:

```
path/to/file.cpp(123): Error: blah blah blah
```

It only accepts:

```
path/to/file.cpp(123) : Error: blah blah blah
```

The key difference is the space between the closing line number parenthesis. I deduced this by adding a custom build step in Visual Studio to echo fake error messages to the console and seeing which ones QtCreator picked up.

To solve this, I created an batch file called msbuild_wrapper.bat which used sed.exe from Cygwin:

```
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" %* | c:\cygwin64\bin\sed.exe 's/):/) :/g'
```

It simply runs msbuild with the given parameters and then uses sed to replace all incidences of "):" with ") :" in the output. In my project settings in QtCreator, I set the compiler to msbuild_wrapper.bat and also added `/clp:NoSummary` to the arguments to stop errors appearing twice.

Once that was in place, QtCreator correctly picks up all errors and warnings and places them in the 'Issues' panel with the correct file and line numbers.